# Accessing elements in matlab, get pixels of color image (array) from indices stored in another array

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, indexing

`A` and `B` are mask indices (row and column respectively) and `C` is an image and I want to note the color values stored in `C` for which the indices are stored in `A` and `B`. If `A` and `B` would be something like `[1, 2, 3]` and `[20, 30, 40]` so I would like to find `C(1, 20, :)`, `C(2, 30, :)` and `C(3, 40, :)`.

If I do `D = C(A, B, :)`, I get an array of size 3x3x3 in this case, however I want an array of size 3x1x3. I know I am messing with the indexing, is there a simple way to do this without writing a loop?

Simply stating, is there a way to do the following without a loop:

```
for i = 1:10
    D(i, :) = C(A(i), B(i), :)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert subindices to linear indices. You can use `sub2ind` for that:

```
r = C(sub2ind([size(C,1) size(C,2) 1],A,B,1*ones(1,length(A))));
g = C(sub2ind([size(C,1) size(C,2) 2],A,B,2*ones(1,length(A))));
b = C(sub2ind([size(C,1) size(C,2) 3],A,B,3*ones(1,length(A))));
```

The n x 1 x 3  result you want would be simply `cat(3, r.',g.',b.')`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like everything is working as it should. In your example you've indexed 9 elements of C using A and B. Then D is a 3x3x3 array with the dimensions corresponding to [row x col x color_mask(RGB)]. Why would the second dimension be reduced to 1 unless B only contained one value (signifying you only want to take elements from one column)? Of course A and B must not contain values higher than the number of rows and columns in C.

```
A = [1 2 3];
B = [20];
D = C(A,B,:);
size(D)
>> 3 1 3
```

EDIT: Ok, I see what you mean now. You want to specify N number of points using A(Nx1) and B(Nx1). Not NxN number of points which is what you are currently getting.

Comment: May be my question was not clear, ofcourse matlab gives a 3x3x3 matrix, but I would like to get the elements corresponding to the points I have in A and B, assuming elements with the same index in A and B represent the same point in C

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like

```
C = C(A,B(i),:);
```

You could use a for statement to get the value of i or set it some other way.

Comment: This will not work and I don't want to use a for loop. You'll need to do D(i, :) = C(A(i), B(i), :) and loop over all the indices